# Salesforce storing decimal values to 3 digits internally , inspite of only 2 decimal field permitted on field

Tags: workflow, decimal

I have a discount and currency field,

While saving formula, currency field gets filed in,

While saving currency , discount field should get filled in.

However, The problem is , Salesforce by default is taking 3 values internally , inspite of only 2 allowed

Comment: can you add some example with screenshots

Comment: A quick search got this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212661&type=1

Answer (score 1):

Eric's comment link [Why is the field of data type number storing more numbers in decimal places than defined?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212661&type=1) contains the key point that the field rounding is performed in user interface logic and if you bypass that by setting a value through Apex code (or a formula based on your experience) you can get more decimal places.

Generally its a bad idea to show users one number (with the UI doing the rounding) but end up using a different number in internal logic as resulting values can end up wrong. For example if three values of 33.3333 are presented rounded as 33.33, a user might expect the sum of those numbers to be 99.99. But if the sum logic is using all 4 decimals the sum will be 100.00.

So in Apex code, make a [setScale](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) call (or otherwise round) just before persisting. In formulas there is a [ROUND](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) function available.